# Android - Query regarding activity lifecycle on changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

**EDIT:** Solution to this question is - [Android - Query regarding activity lifecycle on changing screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716812/android-query-regarding-activity-lifecycle-on-changing-screen-orientation/29717168#29717168)

I'm starting Android development and am facing problems regarding activity lifecycle. I have an `Activity A` that calls `Activity B` in its `onCreate()` method (`Activity B` has a custom grid view inside a relative layout).

When in `Activity B`, if the screen orientation remains unchanged and back button is pressed, as expected it goes to `Activity A`'s `onResume()` method. However, on changing screen orientation while in `Activity B`, on later pressing back button, it goes to `Activity A`'s `onCreate()` method thereby recreating `Activity B` (as `Activity A` calls `B` in its `onCreate()`). Only on pressing the back button twice does it go back to `Activity A`'s `onResume()` method. How do I ensure that on changing orientation, I go to `Activity A`'s `onResume()` by pressing back button just once?

I've tried including:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

in `Activity B` in manifest and hence this avoids calling `Activity B`'s `onCreate` on changing orientation but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Start activity B for result from activity A.

Comment: Activity A is base, all onResume and onBack work with it, End.
On head of that you start Activity B, with it's onResume and onBack classes.
On rotation, B is re-created, not A, since you are in B.
I think you must change the way you start B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. Since the screen orientation had changed while in Activity B, Activity A was getting recreated (different orientation than earlier). So all that was needed was to add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

to Activity A in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Activity A is base, all onResume and onBack work with it, End.
On head of that you start Activity B, with it's onResume and onBack classes.
On rotation, B is re-created, not A, since you are in B.
I think you must change the way you start B.
Or onResume of B, finish() B. then in onResume A start B again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've posted a working solution to my question. I needed to add android:configChanges to Activity A as well.